# Android Webview Websocket only works on localhost

Tags: android, websocket, webview

I'm creating an app which use websocket connection to send/receive message and Wamp as server with Ratchet.

All works if I use my local ip

```
socket  = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.15:8080')
```

but when I enter my wan ip, WebSocket always show error {"isTrusted":true}, it does not want to start.

I added port forwarding on my modem: Wan Port 8080 Local Port 80, and tested with an html file via browser http://mywanip:8080/test.html and it works.

WampServer version 3.2.6 64bit

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem changing port mapping on modem:
Wan Port 8080
Local Port 8080
beacuse ratchet websocket server is listening on port 8080